# Error package does not exist java

Tags: java, import, package

I am trying to import a package I created, my file structure is as follows:

- javacode

  - tester.java
  - mypackage

    - Cram.class

In my tester I import the package using: `import mypackage.Cram;`
but when I try to compile my tester.java I get the following
error: package mypackage does not exist. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the error; algo is my tester.java and pack is mypackage.

```
algo.java:6: error: package pack does not exist
import pack.Cram;
           ^
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are compiling all of your files at the same time, then you should just be able to use your code as-is, provided that you have your classes defined properly and in the directory structure as indicated by your `package` keyword.

Suppose you have the following directory tree (as in your original post):

```
javacode
    Tester.java
    mypackage
        Cram.java
    classes
        <.class files will be placed here later>
```

And the following classes defined:

Tester.java:

```
import mypackage.Cram;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cram c = new Cram();
        c.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Cram.java:

```
package mypackage;

public class Cram {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello from Cram!");
    }
}
```

You can compile all of these files into a single directory (usually, IDE's will compile to a "classes" or "bin" directory) with the following command:

```
> javac -d classes Tester.java mypackage\Cram.java
```

This will place all your class files in the directory "classes"

```
classes
   Tester.class
   mypackage
       Cram.class
```

You can then run by using:

```
> java -cp classes Tester
```

And produce output:

```
Hello from Cram!
```

If you are compiling your package separately from Tester.java, like a library, then you can do the same thing, just with some separate commands.

Compile `mypackage.Cram`:

```
> javac -d classes mypackage/Cram.java
```

This will put the .class files in the same classes directory. When you try to compile Tester.java (which uses `mypackage.Cram`), you simply tell the compiler where your classes are:

```
> javac -d classes Tester.java
```

and then run:

```
> java -cp classes Tester
```

produces the same output.

My guess is, your classes and names are all mangled, and Java expects them to follow a convention.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile, it is looking for .java files. Put the Cram.java file in there, and try compiling again.

Change your import in Algo.java. You are looking for pack.Cram, and you have indicated it is mypackage.Cram.

Comment: Also, make sure Cram.java declares it is in a package.

package mypackage;

public class Cram {
...
}

Comment: Yep I have that too, I've looked at quite a few forum posts but none have seemed to help.

Comment: See my edit. Your import is looking for pack.Cram, not mypackage.Cram.